How to exclude some classes when using jacococli.jar to generate coverage report
I have a project that contains many modules. In order to accelerate the speed of unit testing, I separated these modules and ran unit testing separately. Then, I hope to merge the results and generate a total test report。for example：

pom.xml
-A
-- pom.xml
-- A1/A11
--A1/pom.xml
--A2/A22
--A2/pom.xml
-B
-- pom.xml
-- B1/B11
--B1/pom.xml
--B2/B22
--B2/pom.xml

I ran unit tests for modules A and B separately and obtained coverage rates. I want to merge the Jacoco.exe files of A and B to generate a new coverage report. The commands are:
java -jar jacococli.jar merge A/A1/target/jacoco.exec, A/A2/target/jacoco.exec,B/B1/target/jacoco.exec,B/B2/target/jacoco.exec --destfile merged.exec
java -jar jacococli.jar report merged.exec  --classes A/A1/target/classes --classes A/A2/target/classes --classes B/B1/target/classes --classes B/B2/target/classes --sourcefiles A --html A/target/report
But I will get an error message:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error while analyzing /A/A1/target/classes/META-INF/versions/11/META-INF/versions/9/javax/xml/bind/ModuleUtil.class.class with JaCoCo 0.8.12.202403310830/dbfb6f2.
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzerError(Analyzer.java:163)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:135)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:158)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeAll(Analyzer.java:195)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeAll(Analyzer.java:228)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeAll(Analyzer.java:223)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeAll(Analyzer.java:223)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeAll(Analyzer.java:223)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeAll(Analyzer.java:223)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeAll(Analyzer.java:223)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeAll(Analyzer.java:223)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeAll(Analyzer.java:223)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.commands.Report.analyze(Report.java:110)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.commands.Report.execute(Report.java:84)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.Main.execute(Main.java:90)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.Main.main(Main.java:105)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't add different class with same name: org/apache/flink/table/planner/delegation/ParserImpl
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.CoverageBuilder.visitCoverage(CoverageBuilder.java:106)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.Analyzer$1.visitEnd(Analyzer.java:100)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.asm.ClassVisitor.visitEnd(ClassVisitor.java:395)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.internal.flow.ClassProbesAdapter.visitEnd(ClassProbesAdapter.java:100)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:749)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:425)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:117)
at org.jacoco.cli.internal.core.analysis.Analyzer.analyzeClass(Analyzer.java:133)
... 14 more
What can i do to  get the report?
